# How to call php function using ajax when reset a form in Wordpress?

Tags: ajax, jquery, wordpress

Hi i was using normal form submission in WordPress plugin settings **options.php**. Now i like to use ajax based form submission in WordPress admin.i can able to do the form submission using ajax by **onsubmit** in form

For submit

```
  <form id="hhh" onsubmit="return sub();">
    <label>FirstName</label>
    <input type="text" name="fname" value="">
     <label>LastName</label>
    <input type"text" name="lname" value="">
    <input type="submit" class="button-secondary" value="save" />
    </form>
```

For reset

```
<form method="post">
<input class="button-secondary" name="reset" type="submit" value="Reset" />
</form>
```

ajax for submit

```
function sub() {
    $.ajax({type:'POST', url: 'options.php', data:$('#hhh').serialize(), success: function(response) {

    }});

    return false;
}
```

i can easily save the value by submit using ajax but for resetting the value i have to call a php function which will reset the form and it will add new default values.How can i achieve this using ajax? Thank

Comment: `$.ajax({type:'GET' […]})`?

Comment: No i want to call a php function from sample.php

Comment: And why can you not use AJAX GET?